How to make packing and unpacking functions generic?
I would like to make these two functions generic:
/**
 * Unpack an element if it is packed.
 * @param data - Data from which to unpack.
 */
export const unpack = (
  data: undefined | string | string[],
  index: number = 0,
): undefined | string => (Array.isArray(data) ? data[index] : data);

/**
 * Pack an element if it is unpacked.
 * @param data - Data to pack.
 */
export const pack = (
  data: undefined | string | string[],
): undefined | string[] =>
  Array.isArray(data) || data === undefined ? data : [data];

Here is my try:
/**
 * Unpack an element if it is packed.
 * @param data - Data from which to unpack.
 */
export const unpack = <T,>(
  data: T,
  index: number = 0,
): T extends unknown[] ? T[number] : T =>
  Array.isArray(data) ? data[index] : data;

/**
 * Pack an element if it is unpacked.
 * @param data - Data to pack.
 */
export const pack = <T,>(data: T): T extends unknown[] | undefined ? T : T[] =>
  Array.isArray(data) || data === undefined ? data : [data];

TypeScript Playground link
For the generic unpack function, TypeScript does not complain. However for the generic pack function, TypeScript generates this error:
Type 'T | (T & ({} | null))[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends unknown[] | undefined ? T : T[]'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends unknown[] | undefined ? T : T[]'.

Is the generic unpack function correctly typed? How to fix the typing of the generic pack function?

TS doesn’t understand the logic that corresponds to a generic conditional return type. You’ll need to use a type assertion or the equivalent to get the compiler not to complain and you’ll have to be careful that you did it right because the compiler won’t be able to check. I’ll show via playground link when I get off mobile

Like this for example. The only reason your first one type checks is because any sneaks in there and shuts off type checking. Neither of them are really guaranteed as safe by the compiler.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thank you, if there’s really no solution other than to use a type assertion, I’ll accept your answer. I’ve renamed my functions and added a second parameter to the first one to make it more generic, so can you use that version for your answer?

TypeScript currently (as of TS5.4) can't use control flow analysis to affect generic type parameters directly.  Inside
const pack = <T,>(data: T): T extends unknown[] | undefined ? T : T[] =>
  Array.isArray(data) || data === undefined ? data : [data];

the type checker can maybe understand that in the true branch of your conditional expression, data is of type T & (any[] | undefined). But the type parameter T is unaffected.  So returning data in that case will fail to type check because you're assigning a T & (any[] | undefined) to a T extends unknown[] | undefined ? T : T[].  You'd like to say that checking data has in implication for T directly. But so far nothing like this is implemented and it's at least somewhat tricky to do it right (e.g., if you have a value t of type  T extends string and you check t === "a", it doesn't mean that T is "a". T could be "a" | "b" | "c" or even just string.  All you know is that "a" is assignable to T, not vice versa).
So it becomes nearly impossible to implement a generic function that returns a conditional type in such a way that the compiler can accurately verify its safety.
The currently open feature requests for improvements to this are microsoft/TypeScript#33014 and microsoft/TypeScript#33912. It's possible that sometime in the near future there will be movement here, since it's mentioned in the TypeScript 5.5 iteration plan at microsoft/TypeScript#57475. But for now it's not part of the language.

All that means if you want to implement a generic function that returns a conditional type, you will probably need to use a type-safety-loosening feature inside the implementation, such as a type assertion or the any type or both:
const pack = <T,>(data: T): T extends unknown[] | undefined ? T : T[] =>
  Array.isArray(data) || data === undefined ? data : [data] as any;

Note that your unpack function didn't need this explicitly because any crept in there.  In the true branch of Array.isArray(data) ? data[index] : data, the type of data becomes T & any[], and thus data[index] becomes T[number] & any, and that any turns the whole thing into any.  Maybe Array.isArray() should narrow to unknown[] instead of any[], but that would break a lot of people's code (see microsoft/TypeScript#43865) so that's the way it is.
Thus it isn't that unpack() compiled with no error because TypeScript actually verified it as safe. It's that the implementation was "infected" by any. Indeed you could make a blatant error and the compiler wouldn't notice:
const unpack = <T,>(
  data: T,
  index: number = 0,
): T extends unknown[] ? T[number] : T =>
  Array.isArray(data) ? data[index] : "WHAAAAA"; // <-- 

All this is to say that whenever you have a generic conditional type, you'll need to take extra care to implement things safely, use type assertions or any to quell the compiler's warnings if necessary, and maybe in the future something better will come along.
Playground link to code

Great. Thanks for the feature requests links

Thank you very much for the detailed answer. So in function unpack, if function Array.isArray would narrow its argument to unknown[] instead of any[], in the first conditional branch, data[index] would be inferred as unknown instead of any. And unknown is not assignable to the T extends unknown[] ? T[number] : T declared return type so TypeScript would complain. And in the second conditional branch, data is inferred as T which is neither assignable to the return type. So as far as I understand TypeScript’s inference is incorrect and the linked pull requests aim to fix it.

What "inference" are you talking about that's "incorrect"? (I can't tell if you're talking about unknown-vs-any or about control-flow-and-generic-types. They are distinct issues but your comment seems to conflate them.) What "pull requests" did I link (I have a bunch of links but they are all to bug reports or feature requests, whereas pull requests would have code that could be merged in if accepted).

I’m talking about the narrowing of generic types with control flow. My understanding is that the declared return types of functions pack and unpack are correct and since the TypeScript inferred return types are not assignable to the declared return types then the inferred return types are incorrect. Yes my bad I meant issues, not pull requests.

You're using "infer" in a nonstandard way; in Array.isArray(data) ? data[index] : data, there's no inference anywhere. There's narrowing of data, but no inference. And those types are not "incorrect", but they're not helping you do what you want. data is of type T; that's not incorrect.  I think the facts of the matter are all laid out in my answer with links to the relevant issues; perhaps we agree on the facts of the matter but not on the descriptions thereof? Not sure where to go from here, if anywhere.

I've always used ‘narrowing’ and ‘inference’ interchangeably. In your narrowing link, there’s this text: ‘Narrowing: How TypeScript infers types based on runtime behavior’. So narrowing seems at least to be a particular kind of inference. In Array.isArray(data) ? data[index] : data, the type of data in the 2nd branch is T so the information that data is not an array is lost, and thus that narrowing seems incorrect to me. Now the type of data in the 1st branch is T & any[] so the information is not lost and thus that narrowing seems correct, yet data[index] is still unassignable.

Rewriting the implementation of unpack with an if statement instead of a conditional operator ? shows the assignability issue of the inferred return type better, cf. this TypeScript Playground.

For the sake of argument, let's say I agree with everything you're saying. What is the goal of this discussion? I'm getting kind of lost with the extended comment chain that doesn't seem to be in service of some particular goal.

The goal was to explain my understanding after having read all the linked issues to make sure it is correct. But I agree that the comment section is not made for extended discussions, especially on advanced topics like that. Thanks again for this great answer.

A question remains: according to you, the inferred return types are not assignable to the declared return types because the inferred return types are incorrect or because the assignability check is incorrect?

Here is the TypeScript Playground for my question.

I wouldn't say either are necessarily "incorrect"; I wouldn't use that term. The problem is that T itself doesn't change. Assigning T to T extends unknown[] | undefined ? T : T[] would be fine if you know T extends unknown[] | undefined is definitely true, but we don't know that without ms/TS#33014. You want to say that Array.isArray(data) || data === undefined implies that T extends uknnown[] | undefined, but it doesn't necessarily (constraints aren't the sames as narrowings). I'd say it's a missing feature. I don't know how else to say it, sorry.
